# How to make a star Triangle in PHP showing loop logic from 1 to 10?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Something like this but i didn't get the right answer the browser shows nothing I want the actual code where I'm making a mistake? plz help it only shows on the browser "; } ?> this i don't understand why

```
* * * * * *
```

i use Adobe DW and Php designer and xampp is also running in c directories

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: If you want help at least take some time and effort to format your question properly, that's quite a mess there. I have taken a guess, but to be honest it is impossible to tell what you are trying to achieve. You must have been able to see what a mess it was, but you expect other people to sort it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Show your code please. If you want like this,

```
 *
 * *
 * * *
 * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
```

Code is (lets say for 10)

```
for($i = 1; $i<=10;$i++){
    for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

But to know your error, show us your code

Answer (score 0):

> Star triangle

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

> Try this code

```
<?php
$sum = "*";
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    call_user_func(function($sum) { echo $sum, "<br/>"; }, str_repeat($sum,$i));
}
?>
```